# How to dismiss keyboard from childViewController which is in containerView in parentViewController?

Tags: ios, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I need to dismiss keyboard which show itself when I click `UITextField` from childView. I need to do this in method (`scrollViewWillBeginEditing`) which is in parentViewController. How can I do it?

EDIT:

I have method in childViewController:

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.textField.text);
}
```

and .h of childViewController:

```
@protocol VVInformationTableViewControllerDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>
-(void)dismissKeyboard;
@end

@interface VVInformationTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, VVInformationTableViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<VVInformationTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

and I try to call it in:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        [self.infoTableController dismissKeyboard];    
}
```

When it is call then NSLog print (null) and keyboard didn't dismiss, but when I call dismissKeyboard from childViewController then it print true value and keyboard dismiss.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
 [self.childView endEditing:Yes];
```

Comment: Then I have error: No visible @interface childView declares the selector 'endEditing'. I try to call method dismissKeyboard which is implemented in childViewController using all delegate and protocols stuff, but it didn't work too.

Comment: here childView means the object your child view controller class,or you can use [self.view endEditing:Yes];